# Paint frame backround in tkinter GUI, bg=arg location in class and change frames size

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame, background-color

where do I need to insert the 'bg="color"' arg to paint the backround of the top frame?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import io
import os

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("640x478")
        self.title("Gil Shwartz GUI Project")
        # self.resizable(0, 0)
        menu = tk.Frame(self, height=250, width=10, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat", height=200, bg="black")

        menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", anchor="w")
        container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)
        menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "MainWelcome", "testPing", "PageOne", "UptimeCheck"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = MainWelcome(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = testPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = UptimeCheck(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Ping Test", bg="royalblue2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="dark violet",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        buttun3 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", bg="pale goldenrod",
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(1))
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="gray40",
                            command=lambda: Menu.terminate(self))

        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        buttun3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


        # button1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # button2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        # button4.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

    def terminate(self):
        exit()

class MainWelcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        # img = Image.open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/gil.jpg')
        # self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        # canvas.create_image((0, 0), image=photo, anchor="center")

class testPing(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")
        self.controller = controller

        self.output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=325, width=580, padx=3, pady=3)
        self.output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)
        # self.output.update()
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self, height=320, width=550, pady=3, padx=3)
        self.textbox.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)

        clearFile = tk.BooleanVar()
        clearFile.set(False)
        urlLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Enter URL : ", padx=7, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        urlInputBox = tk.Entry(self)
        urlInputBox.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        fileNameLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Filename: ", bg="skyblue1")
        fileNameInputBox = tk.Entry(self)
        clearFileLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Clear File?", padx=5, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        clearFileRadioYes = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="yes", value=True, var=clearFile, bg="skyblue1",
                                           command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioNo = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="no", value=False, var=clearFile, bg="skyblue1",
                                          command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        urlSubmitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, height=2,
                                    command=lambda: self.pingURL(urlInputBox.get(),
                                                                 clearFile.get(), fileNameInputBox.get()))
        clearFieldsButton = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Fields", padx=5, pady=5,
                                      command=lambda: self.clear_boxes(urlInputBox, fileNameInputBox))

        urlLabel.pack(anchor="w")
        urlInputBox.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        fileNameLabel.pack(anchor="w", padx=7, pady=5)
        fileNameInputBox.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        clearFileLabel.pack(anchor="w")
        clearFileRadioYes.pack(anchor="w")
        clearFileRadioNo.pack(anchor="w")
        urlSubmitButton.pack(anchor="w", pady=1)
        clearFieldsButton.pack(anchor="w")

    @classmethod
    def clear_boxes(self, urlInputBox, fileNameInputBox):
        urlInputBox.delete(0, "end")
        fileNameInputBox.delete(0, "end")

    @classmethod
    def callback(self, clearFile):
        print(f'Clear file = {clearFile}')  # Debugging Mode - check Radio box Var.

    def pingURL(self, host, clearFile, filenameInputBox):

        print(clearFile, filenameInputBox)  # Debugging - Input Validation
        if clearFile is True and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is True and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_no(self, host):

        startprocs = []
        # nextprocs = []
        lastprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + WriteFile",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput",
                          target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output, args=(host,))
        # proc3 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + Generate PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        # proc4 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        proc5 = mp.Process(name="Remove first line + Write new default file",
                           target=self.delete_default_lines)

        startprocs.append(proc1)
        startprocs.append(proc2)
        # startprocs.append(proc3)
        # startprocs.append(proc4)

        # nextprocs.append(proc1)

        lastprocs.append(proc5)

        for s in startprocs:
            s.start()

        for s2 in startprocs:
            s2.join()

        # for n in nextprocs:
        #     n.start()
        #
        # for p in nextprocs:
        #     p.join()

        for l in lastprocs:
            l.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_no(self, host):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Append to default file",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Print Output", target=self.clr_no_fn_no_printoutput, args=(host,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()

        for p in nextprocs:
            p.start()

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + userFilename + Write to file",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + user filename + Print output",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))
        proc3 = mp.Process(name="Remove Empty Lines from user filename",
                           target=self.delete_userfile_lines, args=(filenameInputBox,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)
        nextprocs.append(proc3)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()

        for np in nextprocs:
            np.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Append to Userfile",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Print Output",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))

        proc3 = mp.Process(name="Remove first line + Write new default file",
                           target=self.delete_userfile_lines, args=(filenameInputBox,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        nextprocs.append(proc3)

        for p in procs:
            p.start()

        for p2 in procs:
            p2.join()

        for n in nextprocs:
            n.start()


    @classmethod
    def delete_default_lines(cls):

        time.sleep(2)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt'

        with open(file, 'r') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()
        os.remove(file)

    @classmethod
    def delete_userfile_lines(cls, filename):

        time.sleep(2)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt'

        with open(file, 'r') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "4", f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        sub.run(f"ping {host}", shell=True, capture_output=True)

    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, proc.stdout.decode())

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_writefile(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default-tmp.txt'
        ping = sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE)
        with open(file, 'w+') as output:
            data = output.read()
            for line in ping.stdout.readlines():
                data += str(line.decode())
            ping.stdout.close()
            output.seek(0)
            output.write(data.lstrip())

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_printoutput(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_writefile(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        print("Append to file function")

        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):

        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        with open(file, 'w') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):

        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

class UptimeCheck(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="This is page 2", bg="honeydew3", relief="flat")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", bg="red")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page 2",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Update**

following  acw1668's answer, how can i make the upper frame 3/4 of the screen instead of 1/2?

[image]

Comment: Either `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=...)` or adding `self.config(bg=...)` after `tk.Frame.__init__(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! why didn't u put that in answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either specify it in the `__init__()`:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=...)
```

Or configure it separately:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
self.config(bg=...)
```